# Center [UIColor colorWithPatternImage]?

Tags: uiview, uiimage, calayer, uicolor

I couldn't find anything on how you can center the 'image' when you use (maybe you can't):

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]]];
```

Setting my `[self setContentMode:UIContentModeCenter];` doesnt help.

Do I have to manually draw the image (either in `drawRect` or set the content of the `CALayer`? Which one if preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the wrong path here: you create a `UIColor` from a pattern (pattern already implies this is a repeating image). All in all- you can't have your pattern not repeat and centered.

If you just want simple image as background of your `UIView`, just add it as a subview and center it.

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourfile.png"];
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage: img];

[yourUIView addSubview: imgView];
imgView.center = CGPointMake(yourUIView.frame.size.width/2, yourUIView.frame.size.height/2);
```

Now - add more subviews to your "`yourUIView`" view and they'll show on top of the image - thus the image becoming the background.

So... no need to draw anything yourself.

Comment: Thanks worked. I cant just set your answer as accepted just yet. Wait an hour or so.

Comment: I used it as a container view instead. MyContainer : UIImageView { } And then added [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];